# The callback in my code seems not working and returns result without the callback function is being applied

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I have written a javascript object 'myMath' as follows:
But in the 'mean' function, callback is not being called.

```
const myMath = {
    square(x){
         return x**2;
    },
    mean(array, callback){
            if(callback){
                    array.map(callback);
            }
            const total = array.reduce((acc,x)=>acc+x);
            return total/array.length;
    }
};
```

When tried to invoke the function as follows output obtained is 2, and not 4.6666..., which is expected.

```
myMath.mean([1,2,3],x=>x**2);
<< 2
```

Why is it so ? And How can I resolve that ?

Comment: the callback is getting called, you just ignore the array of results

Comment: I thought callback is not being called. Now I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array. It's that one you need to work with after the map operation.

```js
const myMath = {
    square(x){
         return x**2;
    },
    mean(array, callback){
       let mapped = callback ? array.map(callback) : array;
       const total = mapped.reduce((acc,x)=>acc+x);
       return total/mapped.length;
    }
};

console.log(myMath.mean([1,2,3],x=>x**2));
console.log(myMath.mean([1,2,3]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Array.map is not "mutating" method, so you should save mapped value:

`array = array.map(callback);`